# I get "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError" when I return a simple HTML page with Angular JS.

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, jinja2

[image: The error message]

[image: the html page I am trying to render]

[image: the flask app that returns the page]

I tried another example with ng-bind. Thats works fine. Is there anything I need to add to get this working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use screenshots to share code. Instead, copy and paste the code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja and Angular both share the use of `{{` and `}}` tags to indicate accessing their variables, so you need to either tell Jinja or Angular to use something else, so they don't collide. Below is how to tell Angular how to use a different tag to indicate a variable call:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');
}]);
```

(Taken from [Loren Howard's guide](http://lorenhoward.com/blog/how-to-get-angular-to-work-with-jinja/))

Comment: thank you! But, this config is bound to ng-app="myApp". Is there a way I can get this config working across all the pages/ng-apps in my application?